# How can I write a complex fraction using HTML/CSS/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fractions

I'd like to be able to write a fraction using HTML/CSS/jQuery (rather than using a TeX renderer or even MathML). At the moment there's a great workaround for writing simple fractions that works if you just have **one term** for both the numerator and the denominator, but once you start using more than one term it looks rather horrible. As an example, using:

> `<sup><font size=-2>x<sup>2</sup> + 3x + 5</font></sup>/<sub><font size=-2>2x</font></sub>`

produces...

<sup>x<sup>2</sup> + 3x + 5</sup>/<sub>2x</sub>

What I'd like is a beautiful horizontal line to define the fraction rather than a backslash. I've tried using `div` tags with `border-bottom` as such, but the output is still quite awful:

```
  <div style="float:left;">Substitute 4 for 'x' in the equation: &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid;font-size:small;text-align:center;">x<sup>2</sup> + 3x + 5</div>
    <div style="font-size:small;text-align:center;">2x</div>
  </div>
```

produces...

[image: div tags for fraction]

What I'm looking for is a HTML/CSS/jQuery fraction that...

- has an easily discernable horizontal line spanning the width of the longest numerator **or** denominator;
- appears inline with the current text (it can slightly exceed the line height of the text, but I don't want it bursting out of it's seams); and
- (not really necessary, but a nice cherry on top) italicised letters (not numbers or brackets).

Can this be done? How? Thanks!

Comment: `<font>` tags? **Seriously**?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I found a better way to do what you were doing. No extra CSS, just some tabular magic.

```
<table><tr><td>
<div style="float:left;">Substitute 4 for 'x' in the equation: &nbsp;</div></td>
 <td> <div style="float:left">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid;font-size:small;text-align:center;">x<sup>2</sup> + 3x + 5</div>
    <div style="font-size:small;text-align:center;">2x</div>
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Tables auto-center-align :D

For more text, add more `<td>`s. Keep text-`<td>`s and math-`<td>`s separate. Add another `<tr>` for a new line.

```
<table><tr><td>
<div style="float:left;">Substitute 4 for 'x' in the equation: &nbsp;</div></td>
 <td> <div style="float:left">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid;font-size:small;text-align:center;">x<sup>2</sup> + 3x + 5</div>
    <div style="font-size:small;text-align:center;">2x</div>
  </div></td>
<td>. If you feel bored, solve this as well:</td>
<td> <div style="float:left">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid;font-size:small;text-align:center;">y<sup>2</sup> + 3x+5y<sup>5</sup> + 5</div>
    <div style="font-size:small;text-align:center;">1000</div>
  </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="float:left;">Substitute 4 for 'x' in the equation: &nbsp;</div></td>
 <td> <div style="float:left">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid;font-size:small;text-align:center;">x<sup>2</sup> + 3x + 5</div>
    <div style="font-size:small;text-align:center;">2x</div>
  </div></td>
<td>. If you feel bored, solve this as well:</td>
<td> <div style="float:left">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid;font-size:small;text-align:center;">y<sup>2</sup> + 3x+5y<sup>5</sup> + 5</div>
    <div style="font-size:small;text-align:center;">1000</div>
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Manishearth!! As your answer [uses less HTML & CSS than mine](http://jsbin.com/3/ecenux/3/edit?html,css,live) I'm going to award you the answer. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Try this: http://www.mathjax.org/

It's used over at https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Thanks @ilivewithian - I didn't want a TeX renderer though.

Answer (score 3):

This is what [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) is for. Here's a jQuery plugin which seems to have a nice implementation: http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2009/12/jslatex-jquery-plugin-to-directly-embed.html

Comment: Thanks Josh. I'm looking to move away from anything that requires external rendering of the fraction.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally suggest [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22164/7433). (it uses HTmL/CSS)

But, if you do not want to resort to a TeX renderer, then you may want to investigate the CSS behind a MathJax fraction with Chrome Inspector.

Go to [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22164/7433), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (in Chrome), use the inspector magnifying glass on the fraction. Then check out the CSS in the sidepane.

Comment: Thanks Manishearth, I can't believe the additional quantity of HTML & CSS inserted! As noted above I'd prefer not to use MathJax.

Comment: @rs77 I know you don't wanna use it, I was thinking that you could check out the CSS, remove superfluous stuff, and use a similar CSS for fracs.

Comment: @rs77: I [posted another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10268873/1198729) that builds upon your example in a very simple manner. I posted it separately since it's fundamentally different from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

[I've made a quick jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFyuz/)

I'm not sure quite what you mean when you said that `div`s and `border`s made it look awful, becuase my solution is quite similar.

It just uses `span`s and `border`s.

It's not perfect: the text does not get aligned to the center, but it's a nice quick alternative to a TeX renderer.

Comment: Thanks ACarter. I never thought to use `span` but it gets difficult to center the question relative to the horizontal fraction line when there's a `<br/>`. [I think I ended up finding the solution, bar the cherry!](http://jsbin.com/3/ecenux/2/edit?html,css,live)