# Creating fractions dynamically with Javascript inside content-editable div

Tags: javascript, math, html, fractions

What I'm developing is a web page that allows the user to enter math equations and phrases into a visual space, without the use of an actual keyboard. So far what I have is the visual space, which is a contenteditable div tag, as well as an area underneath with input buttons for placing numbers and mathematical symbols into said div. Now what I need is some way of allowing the user to enter fractions into the div. I thought of maybe somehow using Javascript to go into and out of subscript/superscript "mode" and stacking numbers on top of each other separated by a line, and then have a button signifying that the user has finished entering numbers into the fraction, but my knowledge of JS is very limited at this point. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I mean fractions are just glorified division. Are you talking about making them look like fractions proper (ie one number on top, dividing line, one on the bottom?)

Comment: Might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267238/how-can-i-write-a-complex-fraction-using-html-css-jquery for visuals and http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/online-calculator.html for how to write JavaScript browser app with help of jQuery

Comment: Sounds like a job for [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get them to be numbers stacked on each other with a divider. And I started by using MathML but couldn't figure out a way to add the characters dynamically.

Comment: You have two problems here: entering a fraction and rendering it. For the latter, [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) could probably help you. For the former, consistency with the rest of your UI is important, so use whatever feels natural in your setup.

Comment: @Ben you can use any pattern you like simply by changing the regex

Answer (score 1):

You have parsing problem here. I used regex to match a predefined pattern I chose 
laTex style `{DIGIT}|{DIGIT}`

```
 function transformFracs() {
 //Grab digits with in {} recording only the numbers
 var regex = /{(\d+)}\|{(\d+)}/;
 //Cache for performance!
 var div = $(this);
 //Replace using html fraction notaion
 var afterReplace = div.html().replace(regex,
     "<sup>$1</sup>" +
     "&frasl;" +
     "<sub>$2</sub>")
 //Replace content of original div
 div.html(afterReplace);
 }
$(".editable").blur(transformFracs);
```

Check out [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/9B4f3/1/) to play around with it.